# Laravel 5 routes not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have a problem with routes. Maybe i am missing something in the configuration.
I can only route to one file.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Those routes are working perfectly, but when i change the file to welcome2 for examle it shows HTTP ERROR 500
so the route

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('welcome2');
});
```

is not working. The file welcome 2 is a renamed copy of welcome and it's located in the same directory.

mod_rewrite is enabled.

.htaccess is working also

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome and welcome2 are located at same place ?

Comment: You need to clear cashe "php artisan cache:clear" & "php artisan view:clear" & "php artisan route:cache"

Comment: @Qazi - yes, they are both in the same directory on the server.

Comment: @Ankur Bhadania - i did it, now the main route is not working also :D

Comment: Hi you have both welcome and welcome2 files?

Comment: Hi, @dyachenko
yes i have them both. The problem is not the files, they are duplicated on the same directory, just with different names

Comment: what do you have in logs `/path_to_your_project/storage/logs/laravel.log`? or in server logs?

Comment: @dyachenko
`[2016-05-18 11:07:10] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException' with message 'Command "route:scan" is not defined.`

and then is stack trace.

I did what AnkurBhadania said, so now it stops in index.php around 

`$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);`

Comment: Thanks all for awnsering, the problem was permissions on laravel.log file.

Answer (score 0):

So, after clearing the cache with
"php artisan cache:clear" & "php artisan view:clear" & "php artisan route:cache" the application fully stopped.
After some ressearch i found it was a problem with permissions on laravel.log file.
Thanks to everyone commented.